# How do I ensure extra application model tables are created when testing a single application in Django?

Tags: django, testing

I've just split one django app into two - it was getting too unfocused and the separation was the best way forward.

However... one of my models now references a model in my newly split off app with a ForeignKey relation.

Now when I run my tests they fail because the test suite isn't creating the models in the split off app.

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: relation "blah" does not exist
```

When i run the test with `verbose = 2` I see that it's not bothering to create those tables. How do I force the test to create these extra tables?

It creates the `auth` tables, some other core django tables and `south_migrationhistory` - and looking at the south code, I can't see where/how it's making sure it gets created on testing!

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a migration that creates the table for the second app? is it in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: it was all in there and working - tables created etc. just the test wasn't - turns out the order of `INSTALLED_APPS` matters more for tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your new app is included in your [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps) setting.

Comment: It was. The site was working - admin showing up etc, foreign keys working. However it seems that running the test does something that means the apps need to be declared in the right order inside INSTALLED_APPS. It was the ordering that threw me. Thanks.